# Bulk data call using RXJS in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I want to send a bulk of data and after completing it, want to move to the next one. For example: 
I have this function:

```
async function test() {
  await sample.sampleStructure()
  await sample.sampleDataAdd()
  await sample.sampleDataGet()
}
```

Where I am calling the 3 functions for each call. But I wanted to send for example 200 data for `await sample.sampleDataAdd()` and if the first 200 data response is 'Success' then it will send the rest of the 200 datas. After completing 1000 datas, I want to move on to the next function call.
So I looked and I think RXJS can provide the solution. But I am not use if is it possible to use the filter and next for this scenario.

```
async function test() {
  await sample.sampleStructure()
  // let observable = Observable.range(1,1000)
  let observable = Observable.create()
  observable
  .filter(aysnc function () {
    await sample.sampleDataAdd()
   })
  .subscribe({
    .next: async function () {
       // await sample.sampleDataAdd()
    },
    .error: function (error) {
      console.log(error)
     }
   })
```

I am very new at rxjs, so there are lots of mistakes as well. Please can anyone help me regarding this matter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all to run jobs in parallel

```
const job1Result = await job1()
const job2 = sample.sampleStructure2()
const job3 = sample.sampleStructure3()
const job4 = sample.sampleStructure4()
const [job2Result, job3Result, job4Result] = await Promise.all([job2, job3, job4])

const job5 = await job5()
```

you could then create a loop that goes through 10 at a time.

If you are going to introduce rxjs, there is a lot more to learn.
and handling rxjs subscriptions and error handling can be quite daunting.
So before you introduce it, try to solve it without it.

Comment: I understand. But in parallel promise, I cant send bulk data in specific function.
for example: I want job2 to run 10000 times whereas job1, job3 should be called only once.